# T4MVC Bug In generated code (Identifier expected)

Tags: t4mvc

I have just installed T4MVC in a new project and I am having the following error:
(I have used T4MVC in previous projects and never had this issue)

`CS1001: Identifier expected`

The error come from this generated code (in file T4MVC.cs):

```
[GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
internal partial class T4MVC_System_Web_Mvc_FileResult : System.Web.Mvc.FileResult, IT4MVCActionResult
{
    public T4MVC_System_Web_Mvc_FileResult(string area, string controller, string action, string protocol = null): base(" ")
    {
        this.InitMVCT4Result(area, controller, action, protocol);
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(System.Web.HttpResponseBase ) { }

    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValueDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

The method `WriteFile` is missing the identifier for `System.Web.HttpResponseBase` paremeter.
Someone having the same issue?
There is a fix available?

Comment: https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/ is the better place to report issues. But please include repro steps.

Comment: @DavidEbbo well, repros steps is only installing T4MVC usig NugetPackage Manager and running the T4 template. I'm using VS 2015, with Areas in it an both types of controllers (MVC And WebApi)

Comment: I will report the issue as suggested

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't happen on all solutions, so there much be something specific about yours that triggers this. That's what I mean by repro.

Comment: Oh wait, I know the issue. Answer coming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known VS issue that was fixed in a VS patch. Simply install from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt634751(VS.140).aspx and it'll take care of it.

See also https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/issues/67.